# JAX-WS: multiple "xsd:schema" under "wsdl:types", why?

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm trying to write test web-service application with separated Ednpoint-s like so:

```
package test;

import ...

public class Main {

    HttpsServer server;
    HashMap<String, Endpoint> endpointMap;

    public Main() {
        try {
            SSLContext ssl = ...
            this.server = HttpsServer.create(
                    new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8089),
                    8089);
            this.endpointMap = new HashMap();
            endpointMap.put("/test11", Endpoint.create(new SOAPService1()));
            endpointMap.put("/test22", Endpoint.create(new SOAPService2()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        server.start();
        for (String uri : endpointMap.keySet()) {
            endpointMap.get(uri).publish(
                    server.createContext(uri));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main().start();
    }
}
```

As a result I get a wsdl available at

```
https://localhost:8089/test11?wsdl
```

with multiple **xsd:schema** under **types**:

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://test1.service.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://test1.service.com" name="TEST1Service">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://test2.service.com" schemaLocation="https://localhost:8089/test11?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://test1.service.com" schemaLocation="https://localhost:8089/test11?xsd=2"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="test">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:test"/>
    </message>
    <message name="testResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:testResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="SOAPService1">
        <operation name="test">
            <input wsam:Action="http://test1.service.com/SOAPService1/testRequest" message="tns:test"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://test1.service.com/SOAPService1/testResponse" message="tns:testResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="TEST1PortBinding" type="tns:SOAPService1">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="test">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="TEST1Service">
        <port name="TEST1Port" binding="tns:TEST1PortBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://localhost:8089/test11"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

And the WSDL available at the second url

```
https://localhost:8089/test22?wsdl
```

does not:

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://test2.service.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://test2.service.com" name="TEST2Service">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://test2.service.com" schemaLocation="https://localhost:8089/test22?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="test">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:test"/>
    </message>
    <message name="testResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:testResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="SOAPServiceInterface2">
        <operation name="test">
            <input wsam:Action="http://test2.service.com/SOAPServiceInterface2/testRequest" message="tns:test"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://test2.service.com/SOAPServiceInterface2/testResponse" message="tns:testResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="TEST2PortBinding" type="tns:SOAPServiceInterface2">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="test">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="TEST2Service">
        <port name="TEST2Port" binding="tns:TEST2PortBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://localhost:8089/test22"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

I want them to be completely separate without knowing about each other, but as you can see the first one even includes the schema of second one.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.
By annotating the service class with

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

it removes extra XSD and solves the problem